# White lines between objects in render

Tags: rendering

I am kind of new to the whole animation aspect and in fact still in high school.
 I am trying to make a Minecraft character rig and I want to make some 3D hair. I did not know how to quite make it so I kind of when just did something pretty simple. It isn't the greatest in any means, but any how the point is every time I render it white lines show up between objects or joined objects. I don't know how to fix this and would like help (a picture is posted below of the problem).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Regarding the white lines, is this in Cycles or BI?

Comment: I apologize for not putting it in the right section. I also got rid of the rig request. As for you gandalf3, I am not exactly sure what it is I would think BI but whatever default is. All I did was got the camera and rendered an image with F12 and it shows the white lines.

Comment: No worries :) The default is BI. Is it possible you could upload your blend or some screenshots of your settings?

Comment: Yeah I will try to upload the blend file. Give me a sec.

Comment: I uploaded it to this site http://www.pasteall.org/blend/25106. I didn't know any other way to upload it. I will also attach the image you need for the material/textures of everything.

Comment: It seems this is caused because the texture is not covering the insides of each object, so the diffuse color is showing through.

Comment: Yeah that does seem to be the problem is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: I would use Maya but being in High School I don't have that kind of money. I want to do animations and gameplay youtube videos, but just don't know when to start.

Comment: Gandalf3 is there a way I could get rid of the diffuse or make it so you cant see it I fixed it a little bit. Here is an updated image.

Comment: Nevermind I think I have fixed it or at least for the most part. Thanks for a little bit of help telling me it was a material issue and it was! :)

Comment: @GarrettLozano Please use the [answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/answering) button below the question to post the solution that worked for you. This is not a forum, we don't update the question with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the texture , but a few tweaks fixed it. First I enabled Face Textures and Face Textures Alpha in the materials tab under the options sub-tab. I then went to the texture tab and under image sampling I changed the filter size from 1.00 to 0.10. This cleared up most if not all the visible white around the objects.

[image]

Comment: Hi Garrett, glad you find your way to fix it. However, I can still notice a few tiny white dots in this image, around the front and side edge of the head. which means, this only works better with certain view angle. I've tried your way, but such problem seem still occurs when viewing from other angle.

Comment: Yeah well on yours I see black or brown lines between objects. I also don't want to shrink the texture because then I won't be able to see the full skin.

Comment: Leon Cheung I think that is all I did maybe more but I don't seen any lines and like maybe 4 white dots per render from different angles. It seems really clean. I like your method as well it just won't work on my character maybe stuff I do in future I am sure.

Comment: Sure, if that's what you may accept.  :)

Answer (score 3):

It's caused by lack of bleeding in UV set, which will show poor result when sampling.

To solve this, just leave some room for the border pixel with the same color (that's what bleeding used for).

[image]

Comment: In this case I don't see a good reason to use a texture at all, because it's one solid color and it's a separate object anyway. Why not just set the diffuse color?

Comment: Yep. Anyway, he's problem seems really about bleeding. :) http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=62269