# Un-hiding faces and double sided textures

Tags: texturing, edit-mode

Typically if you look at the back of a textured face you don't see anything but a transparent square.

Is there any way you could make the front and back of the face textured without flipping the direction of the face?

Also, how can you unhide the faces that you previously hidden with <kbd>H</kbd>?

Comment: Please try to avoid asking more than one question in a single post. (It's `Alt+H`, but for future reference that should be a separate question in a separate post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BI both sides of a face should be textured by default in the render.

If you mean in the viewport, you can switch the viewport shading to *Textured* in *3D view > Header* and set the shading to *GLSL* in *3D view > Properties region (<kbd>N</kbd>) > Shading*. Also make sure that *Backface Culling* is disabled in the same panel.

Note that you will need to add lamps to the scene, or enable temporarily [*Shadeless*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Options#Shading) in *Properties > Material > Shading*.
Shadeless is good for editing purposes where you want to see the texture everywhere (no shadows or shading). Note that this will affect the final render, so remember to disable it when you are done.

For [unhiding](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Vertex_Groups/Weight_Paint#Hide.2FUnhide_Faces) faces, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>, or *3D view > Header > Mesh > Show/Hide > Show hidden* in edit mode.

Comment: Well I am a bit confused now. LOL. Sorry for asking 2 questions in one. I changed all my settings to what you have but now my character is black. Also I don't know what I am doing wrong but I go into edit mode click H on a selected face then click Alt+H and the face is still missing.

Comment: @GarrettLozano Strange. It works for me.. Try it from the *Mesh* menu. Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: Here is the link for the file upload: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/25235. I have all these simple questions because I am still in high school and have worked with blender for 2 weeks.

Comment: Thanks. There's nothing wrong with that, (everyone's new at some point) but just try to put one question per post. (this site is a bit different from a forum, in that there is supposed to be one question and several answers which get voted to the top)

Comment: It seems the reason your model appears black is there are no lamps in the scene.

Comment: Alright well that fixed it is there a way to fix the unhide?

Comment: @Pixels_ Did you try it from the menu? (I'm not sure why `Alt+H` wouldn't work. What OS are you using?)

Comment: Yeah it works from the menu but the shortcut doesn't work not even for join meshes (Ctrl+J)? They use to work but now they don't I don't know why?

Comment: @Pixels_ Is caps lock on? (sounds dumb but it's got me before.. :P) Can you find the shortcuts in *User preferences > Input*? What about trying *File > Load factory settings*?

Comment: @gandalf3: There is a small point lamp in the scene, very high. But I think it doesn't matter, since the scene has already got Evironment Lighting set.

Comment: @Pixels: Btw, Are you facing a render black issue or a 3D View black issue? Since the camera is very far from the character. If it's for 3D View, try relocate your texture again, until you can view from the texture/material preview panel. I downloaded and relocated the texture from your previous post here http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3761/696 and relocate the texture, no problem for me currently.

Comment: I am facing a 3D view black issue but it is fixed with a lamp near the object. The only thing is some uneven lighting, but oh well. I also got my shortcuts to work Join (Ctrl+J) was working I was just clicking Alt not Ctrl and the Reveal Hidden still didnt work so I changed it to Ctrl+Alt+H. It now works everything is fine now I don't know why it was all screwed up. The question I thought would be the easiest I have asked thus far turned out to be the most complicated. LOL :) Thanks guys!

Comment: @Pixels, if the shortcut didn't work, you may consider whether there is another application/software that you are running registering the same shortcut.

Comment: @LeonCheung Environment lighting does not affect GLSL shading (in the viewport) though. I think the OP meant the viewport, I tested it and it does come out black. (the point light is too high to register in GLSL view)

Comment: @Pixels_ To get even lighting in the 3D view you could enable *Shadeless* in the material settings. (this will affect the render so remember to disable it after you are finished using it)

Comment: @gandalf3 Ah, you are right about that. I just used Rendered mode in Viewport when testing, that's why I can see the tex.