# Fix seams on texture

Tags: texturing, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

I am using a rig made by someone as a prop in my scene, but it has these borders / seams on the texture. I think it may be because the model is divided a lot, or it could be something else. Picture:
[image: Seam 1]

I googled this, but I didn't find anything about this problem. Can someone tell me how to fix this or show me a tutorial? Also, I am a beginner so excuse me if this is a dumb question.

Project file to recreate problem: http://www.mediafire.com/download/raedxiikrh3w75p/File.zip

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3761/599. This is caused by lack of bleeding in the texture, see [Leon Cheung's answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3774/599).