# black line between textures

Tags: mesh, texturing

I merged textures alongside their meshes but now there is a black line between each texture.How can I fix this error?
dropbox file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n2qsug7e6r341o0/beach%20model.blend?dl=0

[image: screenshot with freehand circles highlighting the white lines that indicate the beginning/end of the new/previous texture part]

Comment: What happens when you render it?

Comment: i apologize because i rushed this question and it ended being worded really poorly. i've merged meshes with their textures and now there are seams(even when rendered) however, as i get closer to the mesh the seams disappear, is there something i should fix or is it fine?

Comment: I'm not sure i get you - when you render an image, the seams are there when you look at the image at full size? I mean not just render view, an actual render, right? Because how you say it sounds to me that it is about how the viewport displays things. If they are gone when you closely, in that case, it's just an artifact of how it's displayed. The definite proof whether there are seams that shouldn't be there would come from looking at a rendered image, it would help if that was in your post.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. Add [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand the texture you used, the UV map and material settings.

Comment: i added the dropbox file, also I rendered it  and the lines where still there

Comment: the issue has to do with the UV maps being lined up with the edges of the image texture with no bleeding. If you scale the UV map slightly in the X axis, those lines disappear. Read this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3774/1853